# Get project name of task in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a multi-project build. Sub-projects are in tree structure (not flat). 
In root build.gradle file I have a method that does some common thing for compilation phase.

I would like to have separate target dir for each subproject. So when I'm compiling whole project I will have own artifacts for each subproject.
Method I mentioned above does compilation, so it needs to know which project it compiles.

If I use "gradle :subproject1:subsubproject1:compile" command then project.name still contains root project name. But I need in runtime to know project of task that called for method.

Questions are:

1. Is it good idea at all to have separate targets for subprojects?
2. How can I understand project of task that called for method inside this method?

Comment: Why do you need to run module/subproject specific tasks? If you run compile from root it should build all the subprojects.

Comment: Yes, but I also want to have ability to compile only subprojects (with dependencies) to speed things up

Answer (score 18):

If the task is defined in the subproject then you can simply use `project.name` to get the name of the project the task is run under.
You can try it out, for example by adding the following code to build.gradle located on the root project:

```
allprojects {
    task printProjName << {
        println ">> " + project.name
    }
}
```

Then, executing the printProjName task will result in an output similar to the one below:

```
:printProjName
>> Gradle
:projA:printProjName
>> projA
:projB:printProjName
>> projB
:projA:projA1:printProjName
>> projA1
:projA:projA2:printProjName
>> projA2
```

Comment: Thx. But method is defined in root project and if I try to println project.name from method, it returns root project name. I assume the only way out is to pass project.name as argument to method

Comment: Right - you can pass the project object to the function and then you'll get access to all project properties.